# Read form .json with php

Tags: php, json

I have some problems with how to read from external json file in php.

I tried this solution:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('/data/usersdata.json'),TRUE);
print_r ($data);
```

In the usersdata.json now is:

```
{"name":"admin","password":"admin","permission":"admin"}
```

My problem is, I can't see anything on the screen, I want to put data from my json file to an $data array, or something to be usable.

Comment: use `print_r($data)` and check, it is decode properly or not.

Comment: Assuming `/data/usersdata.json` exists, your code _should_ work.

Comment: If it does exists, check the permissions. If you're running it from a web server, the user trying to access it might be `apache` or `nginx` or something.

Comment: Try `data/usersdata.json` I think data is not your root directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't read from .json file to append it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953579/i-cant-read-from-json-file-to-append-it)

Comment: I tried on xampp 3.2.2

Comment: You've already asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953579/i-cant-read-from-json-file-to-append-it). You have to use absolute or relative path. “/data/usersdata.json” is invalid path for your OS. If you activate error reporting, you will see the error.

Comment: Sorry, but no, that's an another thing, because here I want to read from json, and there I got an answer which use "file_put_contents" but that not make an valid json... and that's a different problem. At this problem, i don't see anything on the screen, and in the code of page the  body is empty...

Comment: It is the exact question, and the answer is the same. Activate error reporting (`error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` at top of your script). You will se *PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/data/usersdata.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory*

Comment: Ok, but how can I concatenate these things, or how can I  put in file to be an valid json after append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on PHP 5.6 (MAMP)

I replicated your example and everything works as expected

```js
try {
    $fileData = file_get_contents('src/data.json');
    $data = json_decode($fileData, true);

    print_r($data);
    
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Output:

```js
Array ( [name] => admin [password] => admin [permission] => admin )
```

- Start using try/catch statements to catch any non-fatal errors
- Make sure [error_reporting is set to E_ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)
- In development mode/stage avoid nesting functions as it makes debugging difficult and less readable. With few lines of code saving a line here and there will not impact your performance.